# In remix, the output result of using Injected Web3 is "-"

Tags: solidity

In remix, using the Javascript VM environment to call the contract method to create a new contract can output a new contract address, but the output result of using Injected Web3 is "-"

How can I solve this problem?

[image][image]

I don't know how i can fix it.

Comment: For injected you need wallet like MetaMask. Do you have any?

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using injected Web3 , im assuming your using metamask as your provider if so i believe you should check the transaction hash on the blockchain scan website rather than checking remix output since remix is trying to get the transaction result and could not parse the output.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. I think, I failed to describe my problem clearly. So, my metamask connected to the test network is local ganache, I connect metamask via ethers and go through a method in the deployed smart contract to create another smart contract object, the method returns the new smart contract address.

Comment: But I found that no result is returned. In my remix, the environment selection java Script VM (Lodon) or (Berlin) has output results. If the environment selected in remix is ​​Injected Web3 or the Web3 provider does not output the address of the new contract.